# Facebook sharer.php parameter "images[0]" stopped supporting?

Tags: facebook, share

Firstly I know the Share function in Facebook has been deprecated. However for some reason I still need to use it without a switch to Like.

I reference to this site for customizing Share contents
http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/

With using all parameters same as the example in the site above (url, title, summary, image), Just the contents different. And the code structure is same too so I suppose don't need to post my code here.

The image still loads on 27 Feb 2013, but can't load on 28 Feb 2013. The situation just same as the demo in the above site. It does not work too.

Demo link: http://www.facebook.com/wordpressdesign?sk=app_235525236461712

For the target page, I have also put in og-image but the Share does not load the image too.

Does anyone face the same situation? Or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are experiencing the same problem.

We are changing the share link to 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

UPDATE: Seems the sharer.php function has been corrected and "images[0]" is working.

Comment: Yes after days of investigation. The only best solution is using facebook dialogs and stream publish. But this requires to setup an App in facebook to have an AppID.

Comment: The disadvantage of feed is that it makes the post "via app" which makes it almost automatically ghettoed to spam, regardless the fact that it was clearly the user's action, not app's. So I'll stick with sharer while it works.

Comment: Not working anymore as of Oct 2014 :( No more overriding parameters for title, desc, or image.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same phenomenon. In my situation, I need a button that is transparent. I am going to try the Like button code and set the image for "f","Like", and number of likes element to transparent via css.